# How to solve integrating an equation by python

Tags: python, symbolic-integration

I am trying to integrate an equation by python. However, I don't understand why the integration doesn't run. The equation I want to integrate is:

[image]

Having:
[image], to find [image] having [image] and [image], with [image].

I am doing this procedure:

```py
from sympy import *

x=symbols('x')
y=symbols('y')
```

```py
Gamma = 0.167
sigma_8 = 0.9
M_8 = 6e14

gamma = (0.3*Gamma+0.2)*(2.92+1/3*log(x/M_8))
sigma = 0.9*(x/M_8)**(-gamma/3)
diff(sigma,x)
print(diff(sigma,x))
```

out:

```
0.9*(1.66666666666667e-15*x)**(-0.0277888888888889*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x) - 0.243430666666667)*(600000000000000.0*(-4.63148148148148e-17*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x) - 4.05717777777778e-16)/x - 0.0277888888888889*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x)/x)
```

Then

```py
import math

dnudM = math.sqrt(0.707)*1.686*(1+y)*diff(sigma,x)
print(dnudM)
```

Out:

```
0.9*(1.66666666666667e-15*x)**(-0.0277888888888889*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x) - 0.243430666666667)*(1.41764430376593*y + 1.41764430376593)*(600000000000000.0*(-4.63148148148148e-17*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x) - 4.05717777777778e-16)/x - 0.0277888888888889*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x)/x)
```

Then

```py
n = (1+(1/x**0.6))*exp(-x**2/2)*dnudM
print(n)
```

And out

```
0.9*(1.66666666666667e-15*x)**(-0.0277888888888889*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x) - 0.243430666666667)*(x**(-0.6) + 1)*(1.41764430376593*y + 1.41764430376593)*(600000000000000.0*(-4.63148148148148e-17*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x) - 4.05717777777778e-16)/x - 0.0277888888888889*log(1.66666666666667e-15*x)/x)*exp(-x**2/2)
```

Finally, I arrive to this point that the integration doesn't produce any output.

```py
n_H = integrate(n, x)
print(n_H)
```

It doesn't show either errors nor output!

Comment: Running the code now and it seems like its running fine, its just taking a very, very long time to complete.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How long did it take for you to run? I tried 30 minutes but I gave up.

Comment: You could look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65830981/how-to-speed-up-symbolic-integration-using-sympy for optimizations

Comment: Mine is still running.  I wrapped the integration call in a some code to check the time to execute, so I'll let you know when it finishes.

Comment: @Caridorc Thank you for the link. I tried to optimize it as                                   
`n_H_final = integrate(n_H, x).transform(log(1.66666666666667e-15*x), z) `                but still no output!

Comment: Does a closed-form formula for the integral even exist? A computer algebra system won't be able to find an elementary antiderivative if one doesn't exist. It can handle some nonelementary ones, but mostly ones which can be expressed in terms of `erf`.

Comment: @dove Just to follow up, my execution finished.  The integration function took 107,187.83 seconds to complete, or nearly 30 hours.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety Thank you for the update. I would appreciate it if you could share the result of the integration. Is it in terms of `erf` as the above comment (John Coleman) expressed? or it's a function which could be plotted?

Comment: @dove I'll post the result as an answer because it's actually too long to fit into a comment

Answer (score 0):

The code you have ran to completion for me, but took nearly 30 hours.
I tweaked a couple of variable names and added in some timer code to track it.

Code:

```
import math
from sympy import *
import time
x=symbols('x')
y=symbols('y')

Gamma = 0.167
sigma_8 = 0.9
M_8 = 6e14

gamma_x = (0.3*Gamma+0.2)*(2.92+1/3*log(x/M_8))
sigma = 0.9*(x/M_8)**(-gamma_x/3)
diff_sigma_x = diff(sigma,x)
print(f"{diff_sigma_x=}\n")

dnudM = math.sqrt(0.707)*1.686*(1+y)*diff_sigma_x
print(f"{dnudM=}\n")

n = (1+(1/x**0.6))*exp(-x**2/2)*dnudM
print(f"{n=}\n")

start = time.time()
n_H = integrate(n, x)
print(f"{n_H=}\n")
end = time.time()

print(f"Time to integrate = {end-start} seconds")
```

Results

```
n_H=-2.10235303142289*(y + 1)*(1.0*Integral(-4.20001660788705e-11*exp(-x**2/2)/(1.66666666666667e-15**(0.0277888888888889*log(x))*x**0.897831723570746*x**(0.0277888888888889*log(x))), x) + 1.0*Integral(-4.20001660788705e-11*exp(-x**2/2)/(1.66666666666667e-15**(0.0277888888888889*log(x))*x**0.297831723570746*x**(0.0277888888888889*log(x))), x) + 1.0*Integral(1.41662964847297e-12*exp(-x**2/2)*log(x)/(1.66666666666667e-15**(0.0277888888888889*log(x))*x**0.897831723570746*x**(0.0277888888888889*log(x))), x) + 1.0*Integral(1.41662964847297e-12*exp(-x**2/2)*log(x)/(1.66666666666667e-15**(0.0277888888888889*log(x))*x**0.297831723570746*x**(0.0277888888888889*log(x))), x))

Time to integrate = 107187.83417797089 seconds
```

Comment: Actually I was wondering what the final result will be. This post only repeated the problem again in the integral form not the final result.